# SSLError when using open_by_key(Spreadsheet ID)

Tags: google-sheets, gspread

I referred to the following site. After completing each setting, I wrote gspread_simple.py which shown the site.
https://qiita.com/164kondo/items/eec4d1d8fd7648217935

As a result, the following error was output (I replaced a folder name under C:\Users with ********).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 496, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1122)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 573, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1122)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 182, in __call__
    response = self.session.request(
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1122)')))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\********\samp\module1.py", line 18, in <module>
    ws = connect_gspread(jsonf,spread_sheet_key)
  File "C:\Users\********\samp\module1.py", line 12, in connect_gspread
    worksheet = gc.open_by_key(SPREADSHEET_KEY).sheet1
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 123, in sheet1
    return self.get_worksheet(0)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 283, in get_worksheet
    sheet_data = self.fetch_sheet_metadata()
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 265, in fetch_sheet_metadata
    r = self.client.request('get', url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 61, in request
    response = getattr(self.session, method)(
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 460, in request
    self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\auth\credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\service_account.py", line 361, in refresh
    access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(request, self._token_uri, assertion)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 153, in jwt_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 105, in _token_endpoint_request
    response = request(method="POST", url=token_uri, headers=headers, body=body)
  File "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 188, in __call__
    six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1122)')))
```

I referred to the following site and so on.
https://qiita.com/vmmhypervisor/items/c8ef0ad87318656facb2

- OS: Windows10
- Python: 3.9

My Python is not 2.7 series.
As a test, I tried the command.

```
pip uninstall -y certifi && pip install certifi==2015.04.28
```

But the output was the same.

And I tried the command.

```
pip install -U certifi
```

But the output was the same.